# LINQ ERROR : Explicit construction of entity type

Tags: linq

i am getting this error at GridView1.DataBind();

**Explicit construction of entity type 'WebApplication1.MUser' in query is not allowed.**

```
 using (var db = new UsersDataContext())
            {
                IEnumerable<MUser> user = from u in db.MUsers
                                          where u.Id == 1
                                          select new MUser {Username = u.Username, Id = u.Id, Password=u.Password, ProjectUsers=u.ProjectUsers };

                GridView1.DataSource = user;

                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
```

how to solve this?

i am following this tutorial
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/21/new-orcas-language-feature-query-syntax.aspx

Comment: What's the code for MUser look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the full Muser object just use:

```
using (var db = new UsersDataContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<MUser> user = from u in db.MUsers
                                      where u.Id == 1
                                      select u;

            GridView1.DataSource = user;

            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

alternatively, if you want to return a custom part of the user (i.e. only some properties from the Muser object) you can use anonymous type as follows.

```
using (var db = new UsersDataContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<MUser> user = from u in db.MUsers
                                      where u.Id == 1
                                      select new  {Username = u.Username, Id = u.Id, Password=u.Password, ProjectUsers=u.ProjectUsers };

            GridView1.DataSource = user;

            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: This second example will not work.  The compiler will complain about not being able to cast an anonymous type to type MUser.  Remember that anonymous types are 100% unusable outside of their original, small context.  These anonymous have a very limited and specific usefulness and should never be returned directly from a query for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about the performance, you should change the query to:

```
 using (var db = new UsersDataContext())
      {
      IEnumerable<MUser> user = from x in
                                  (from u in db.MUsers
                                   where u.Id == 1
                                   select u).AsEnumerable()
                                select new MUser { Username = x.Username, Id = x.Id, Password = x.Password, ProjectUsers = x.ProjectUsers };

      GridView1.DataSource = user;
      GridView1.DataBind();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

but anonymous type can't Serialize in WCF.

Answer (score 0):

You can't construct an entity type in a query.  MS thinks developers are too dumb and will confuse themselves (among other things).  A quick, easy, and inefficient fix...

```
using (var db = new UsersDataContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<MUser> user = from u in db.MUsers.AsEnumerable()
                                      where u.Id == 1
                                      select new MUser {Username = u.Username, Id = u.Id, Password=u.Password, ProjectUsers=u.ProjectUsers };

            GridView1.DataSource = user;

            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

I wouldn't recommend this for a product environment as it will load the entire table but I've used it for an internal app for personal use. I would recommend creating an overloaded model.